# Is it safe to export apple developer account from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

Our vendor is asking us to export developer account from Xcode. Is it safe to export developer account and provide .developerprofile file to them and if not what would be consequences of it.

Comment: I wouldnt recomment this for a secured operational company or like bank organization. 1st option We should give the profile and p12 only for that particular app. 2nd option is to let them have thier own account and sign the IPA with that later you should have a resign script to resign the IPA with your account details (we do the same), 3rd option: let them drive down with their source code and you can ask them to enter the details and trash it once the IPA generation and upload is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is potentially safe to export developer account from xcode. But exported developer account becomes vulnerable for misuse if they are not protected by a password. So to avoid misuse of your developer accounts, you should always protect it using a strong password.

One thing more, if your are exporting developer accounts, it will export all your developer account stored in your xcode preferences. It means the person who will use your exported developer accounts, will also get access to provisioning profiles and certificates for the developer account which he not meant for their use.

Comment: Also, it is not explicitly mentioned in the answer, but it is important to point out, that the person you give those files to will be able to sign apps as if they are your company!  If it contains and enterprise distribution profile / cert, they will be able to send apps to devices and people who have trusted your company dev profile will be able to run the apps on their devices without having to trust a new profile.

Comment: A best practice would be for them to provide you the binary and you re-sign it.

Comment: I have one more question what is the difference between ipa created by dragging .app file into iTunes and ipa created by archive from xcode. And if there is no difference then why xcode ask for sign in into developer account while exporting ipa but no sign in required to create it from itunes

Comment: It's both same as if you open the xcarchive file it's the .app file inside it. If you drag that , its same as dragging the IPA. this is because your archive is only created after compiling with the right profile and certs and middle stage of IPA creation. Hence in few cases, people pass xcarchive or IPA to resign the apps which doesnt have source code access. Note that the drag to iTunes is legacy process , avoid using that as Apple recommends Xcode so your validations and all entitlements are taken care of.